# Can not read JSON returned array in Swift like Python enumerate

Tags: python, json, swift

I am trying to replicate the following lines of python code from the https://github.com/joshfraser/robinhood-to-csv repo from GitHub in order to read my transaction history.

```
orders = robinhood.get_endpoint('orders')
paginated = True
page = 0
while paginated:
    for i, order in enumerate(orders['results']):
        executions = order['executions']
        instrument = robinhood.get_custom_endpoint(order['instrument'])
        fields[i + (page * 100)]['symbol'] = instrument['symbol']
        for key, value in enumerate(order):
            if value != "executions":
                fields[i + (page * 100)][value] = order[value]
        if order['state'] == "filled":
            trade_count += 1
            for key, value in enumerate(executions[0]):
                fields[i + (page * 100)][value] = executions[0][value]
        elif order['state'] == "queued":
            queued_count += 1
    # paginate
    if orders['next'] is not None:
        page = page + 1
        orders = robinhood.get_custom_endpoint(str(orders['next']))
    else:
        paginated = False
```

Where we also have

```
def get_endpoint(self, endpoint=None):
        res = self.session.get(self.endpoints[endpoint])
        return json.loads(res.content.decode('utf-8'))
```

I have thus been working on the following iOS code. I work with this code in an XCode playground so feel free to make one to follow along

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let LoginEndpoint:String = "https://api.robinhood.com/api-token-auth/"
let LoginRequestData:[String : String] = ["username": "EmailAdress", "password": "Password"]
let OrdersEndpoint:String = "https://api.robinhood.com/orders/"


func httpReq(type: String, url: String, body:[String : String], header:[String : String]) -> ([String : Any]?, Data?, String?){
    let url = URL(string: url)
    var returnData:([String : Any]?, Data?, String?)? = nil
    if let url = url {
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url) as URLRequest
        request.httpMethod = type
        var postString = ""
        for (key, value) in body {
            if (postString != "") {
                postString += "&"
            }
            postString += "\(key)=\(value)"
        }
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

        for (key, value) in header {
            request.addValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
        }

        let _ = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                do {

                    let jsonSerialized = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any]
                    returnData = (jsonSerialized, data, nil)
                } catch (_) {
                    returnData = (nil, data, "JSON Parse Erro")
                }
            } else if let error = error {
                returnData = (nil, nil, error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }).resume()
    }

    while (returnData == nil) {}

    return returnData!
}

let tokenQuery = httpReq(type: "POST", url: LoginEndpoint, body: LoginRequestData, header: [:])
if let token = tokenQuery.0?["token"] {
    print("token \(token)")
    let historyQuery = httpReq(type: "GET", url: OrdersEndpoint, body: [:], header: ["Authorization": "Token \(token)"])
    if let results = historyQuery.0?["results"], let countString = historyQuery.0?["count"] {
    }
}
RunLoop.main.run()
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

So as you can see I am using the auth token to get to the orders endpoint. I am indeed getting a good response from the orders endpoint but I have no clue how to interpret it.

It would seem from the python code that it is returning an array of JSON objects however I cant figure out how to get to that array in swift. I am not even sure if I am decoding it properly.  The funny thing is when you look at the object returned in Playgrounds it would seem XCode knows that there is an array going on. How do I get to it?

Comment: Your `while (returnData == nil) {}` is a super-bad code to use in actual apps. Even if you are writing an experimental code, you should better write a right code, and that may be affecting _it would seem XCode knows that there is an array going on_.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really get a good idea of the information being returned by your service, because of the lack of credentials.

However, check out [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). It's a really good library, and is extremely helpful with handling JSON data in Swift. It should solve your JSON handling issues.